# Dell XPS 13 9380 Shuts Down after Waking from Suspend

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, dell, shutdown

I have a Dell XPS 13 9380 running Xubuntu 18.04. Xubuntu is the only OS on the machine. My kernel version is 4.18.0. I have successfully flashed the most recent BIOS update from Dell's site. I have also implemented the solution from the first comment on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/8b6eci/xp_13_9370_battery_drain_while_suspended/). Unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue.

My current issue is that the machine will seem to suspend but when I press the power button to bring it up, the screen flashes once then goes dark. I press the power button once more and the Xubuntu logo appears but then the machine shuts down. This happens every time I attempt to bring it out of suspend.

Are there settings that I should be aware of for fixing this issue?

**Update**: Someone on reddit suggested [this workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ccxdrf/shut_down_when_waking_from_suspend_xubuntu_1804/etq58zs?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x). It resolves the issue. But it requires uninstalling light locker and installing xscreensaver.